# netbeans - How to shutdown a Apache Storm's Topology in Netbeans?

Tags: maven, netbeans, apache-storm

My project uses Maven.
To execute the topology, I simply run the Topology file in Netbeans. The thing is that I don't know how to shutdown it.
I don't want to stop the execution of the program at all (Stop Button). I want to tell Topology that it needs to shutdown.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to use the stop button? Seems fine to me...

An alternative is to sleep for a little bit and then shutdown your cluster using Storm's API:

```
LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
LOG.info("Submitting local topology, will be shutdown in 60s");
cluster.submitTopology("CountingTopology", conf, builder.createTopology());
Thread.sleep(60000);    
cluster.shutdown();
```

If it were running on a cluster you'd use Storms CLI to run a command like `storm kill topology-name` which is basically a big stop button. :)

Comment: I don't thitk stopping calls the cleanup method from bolts.

Comment: Which is pretty realistic because cleanup may not be called in production either.

Comment: But I'm testing things, so for now I want the cleanup to be called.

Comment: And your answer is good, is what I was using, but I don't always know the exactly time to shutdown.

Comment: I haven't tried it but maybe you could have a separate app you could run which gets an instance of `LocalCluster` and calls shutdown?